# Restoring an Oracle Backup Properly

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-10g, restore, rman

I've been trying to do a proper restore of a database for weeks now and I'm convinced that I'm doing something simple wrong. I took a cold backup of the database before an update to an application using this command:

`backup database include current controlfile;`

the database has been running in `noarchivelog` mode if that matters. When I run the following command:

`list backup recoverable`

I see the backup I took on that day. Then I run the following commands

```
shutdown abort
startup nomount
restore database
```

Now I have to open the database. If I run `sql 'alter database open'` in rman I get the following error

```
ORA-01190: control file or data file 1 is from before the last RESETLOGS
ORA-01110: data file 1: '+DATA/db-name/datafile/system.333.741265951'
```

Earlier I restored the controlfile from the backup and it is no longer listed in output of the `list backup recoverable` command.

If I run the following command `sql 'alter database open resetlogs'` the command will work and the database will open, but my application will throw errors that I'm sure are coming from the recent update that was applied.

I think using the `resetlogs` flag is making it so I'm no longer using a backup but I'm not sure what to do.

I'm new to this DBA stuff especially with oracle. Sorry for the length of this post but I want to get all the details out.

EDIT: currently neither commands `alter database open resetlogs` or `alter database open noresetlogs` work in opening the DB.

EDIT: displaying backup output:

`RMAN> list backup;`

`List of Backup Sets`

`===================`

`BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time`

`------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------`

`1       Full    121.27M    DISK        00:00:19     29-SEP-11`
`BP Key: 1   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: YES  Tag: TAG20110929T160134`
`Piece Name: /u02/backups/dbname/dbname_18mnp8av_1_1_20110929_1`
`List of Datafiles in backup set 1`
`File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Name`

`---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----`

`2       Full 29134673   29-SEP-11 +DATA/dbname/datafile/sysaux.332.741265959`
`5       Full 29134673   29-SEP-11 +DATA/dbname/datafile/pluto5.327.741268543`
`BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time`

`------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------`

`2       Full    186.50M    DISK        00:00:25     29-SEP-11`
`BP Key: 2   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: YES  Tag: TAG20110929T160134`
`Piece Name: /u02/backups/dbname/dbname_17mnp8av_1_1_20110929_1`
`List of Datafiles in backup set 2`
`File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Name`

`---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----`

`1       Full 29134673   29-SEP-11 +DATA/dbname/datafile/system.333.741265951`
`3       Full 29134673   29-SEP-11 +DATA/dbname/datafile/undotbs1.331.741265965`
`4       Full 29134673   29-SEP-11 +DATA/dbname/datafile/users.329.741265973`
`BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time`

`------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------`

`3       Full    1.05M      DISK        00:00:03     29-SEP-11`
`BP Key: 3   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: YES  Tag: TAG20110929T160134`
`Piece Name: /u02/backups/dbname/dbname_19mnp8bp_1_1_20110929_1`
`Control File Included: Ckp SCN: 29134673     Ckp time: 29-SEP-11`
`BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time`

`------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------`

`4       Full    9.36M      DISK        00:00:01     29-SEP-11`
`BP Key: 4   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20110929T160205`
`Piece Name: /u02/backups/dbname/ctldbname_c-3237489303-20110929-00`
`SPFILE Included: Modification time: 29-SEP-11`
`SPFILE db_unique_name: dbname`
`Control File Included: Ckp SCN: 29134673     Ckp time: 29-SEP-11`
`BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time`

`------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------`

`5       Full    1.05M      DISK        00:00:02     22-DEC-14`
`BP Key: 5   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: YES  Tag: TAG20141222T172206`
`Piece Name: /u02/backups/dbname/dbname_1cpqqnpv_1_1_20141222_1`
`Control File Included: Ckp SCN: 704426960    Ckp time: 22-DEC-14`
`BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time`

`------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------`

`6       Full    303.91M    DISK        00:00:52     22-DEC-14`
`BP Key: 6   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: YES  Tag: TAG20141222T173133`
`Piece Name: /u02/backups/dbname/dbname_1fpqqobn_1_1_20141222_1`

`List of Datafiles in backup set 6`

`File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Name`

`---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----`

`1       Full 704427620  22-DEC-14 +DATA/dbname/datafile/system.333.741265951`
`3       Full 704427620  22-DEC-14 +DATA/dbname/datafile/undotbs1.331.741265965`

`BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time`

`------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------`

`7       Full    1.05M      DISK        00:00:01     22-DEC-14`
`BP Key: 7   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: YES  Tag: TAG20141222T173133`
`Piece Name: /u02/backups/dbname/dbname_1gpqqode_1_1_20141222_1`
`Control File Included: Ckp SCN: 704427620    Ckp time: 22-DEC-14`

`BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time`

`------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------`

`8       Full    363.18M    DISK        00:01:14     22-DEC-14`
`BP Key: 8   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: YES  Tag: TAG20141222T173133`
`Piece Name: /u02/backups/dbname/dbname_1epqqobm_1_1_20141222_1`
`List of Datafiles in backup set 8`
`File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Name`

`---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----`

`2       Full 704427620  22-DEC-14 +DATA/dbname/datafile/sysaux.332.741265959`
`4       Full 704427620  22-DEC-14 +DATA/dbname/datafile/users.329.741265973`
`5       Full 704427620  22-DEC-14 +DATA/dbname/datafile/pluto5.327.741268543`

EDIT: more backup output:

`RMAN> list backup recoverable;`

`List of Backup Sets`
`===================`

`BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time`

`------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------`

`1       Full    121.27M    DISK        00:00:19     29-SEP-11`
`BP Key: 1   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: YES  Tag: TAG20110929T160134`
`Piece Name: /u02/backups/dbname/dbname_18mnp8av_1_1_20110929_1`
`List of Datafiles in backup set 1`
`File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Name`

`---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----`

`2       Full 29134673   29-SEP-11 +DATA/dbname/datafile/sysaux.332.741265959`
`5       Full 29134673   29-SEP-11 +DATA/dbname/datafile/pluto5.327.741268543`

`BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time`

`------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------`

`2       Full    186.50M    DISK        00:00:25     29-SEP-11`
`BP Key: 2   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: YES  Tag: TAG20110929T160134`
`Piece Name: /u02/backups/dbname/dbname_17mnp8av_1_1_20110929_1`
`List of Datafiles in backup set 2`
`File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Name`

`---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----`

`1       Full 29134673   29-SEP-11 +DATA/dbname/datafile/system.333.741265951`
`3       Full 29134673   29-SEP-11 +DATA/dbname/datafile/undotbs1.331.741265965`
`4       Full 29134673   29-SEP-11 +DATA/dbname/datafile/users.329.741265973`

`BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time`

`------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------`

`4       Full    9.36M      DISK        00:00:01     29-SEP-11`
`BP Key: 4   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20110929T160205`
`Piece Name: /u02/backups/dbname/ctldbname_c-3237489303-20110929-00`
`SPFILE Included: Modification time: 29-SEP-11`
`SPFILE db_unique_name: dbname`

`BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time`

`------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------`

`6       Full    303.91M    DISK        00:00:52     22-DEC-14`
`BP Key: 6   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: YES  Tag: TAG20141222T173133`
`Piece Name: /u02/backups/dbname/dbname_1fpqqobn_1_1_20141222_1`
`List of Datafiles in backup set 6`
`File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Name`

`---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----`

`1       Full 704427620  22-DEC-14 +DATA/dbname/datafile/system.333.741265951`
`3       Full 704427620  22-DEC-14 +DATA/dbname/datafile/undotbs1.331.741265965`

`BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time`

`------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------

`8       Full    363.18M    DISK        00:01:14     22-DEC-14`
`BP Key: 8   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: YES  Tag: TAG20141222T173133`
`Piece Name: /u02/backups/dbname/dbname_1epqqobm_1_1_20141222_1`
`List of Datafiles in backup set 8`
`File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Name`

`---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----`

`2       Full 704427620  22-DEC-14 +DATA/dbname/datafile/sysaux.332.741265959`
`4       Full 704427620  22-DEC-14 +DATA/dbname/datafile/users.329.741265973`
`5       Full 704427620  22-DEC-14 +DATA/dbname/datafile/pluto5.327.741268543`

Comment: EDIT: Got the db to open properly by running `recover database` and then opening with `resetlogs`. but i'm fairly sure this undid the backup. does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: When you say _"errors that i'm sure are coming from the recent update that was applied"_, do you mean that you made changes to the database after taking the backup and those changes are gone after the restore? If so, that's exactly what should happen.

Comment: no im saying that those errors are still in the database after the restore. i have an application that worked before an upgrade. after the upgrade changes were made to the DB. which are causing errors. even though im restoring the database im still getting these errors which leads me to believe that im not actually restoring the database.

Comment: Your belief seems wrong. If `restore database` completes successfully, you have a copy of the database as of the time of backup. You need to find an objective way of verifying the database contents.

Comment: If you backup the control file after your cold backup, and if the newer backup of the control file is used, then the control file is too new for the backup. Hence you would need to do recovery. For example if you have auto backup of the control file setup, it might backup the control file after your cold backup finishes. Make sure that you restore the correct backup of the control file, then you should not need to recover the database.

Comment: @Gandolf989 i'm using the control file from the cold backup. when i took the cold backup it included the control file. earlier today i `restored` that control file before doing a `restore database`. the database would not open until i did a `recover database`. do you suggest i use an older controlfile? there is a controlfile from 3 years ago. not sure if using this would corrupt the system.

Comment: @happiness_runs try to run this command "`restore controlfile from 'control_file_path';`" and make sure there is no error in the process  before using this one "restore database", since the error mean the control file is older than the recent " ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS"

Comment: I'll add that the reason you cannot see the backup in RMAN after restoring the controlfile is because when you're not using a recovery catalog database, backup details are stored in the controlfile.

Comment: I hope for your sake that this is development.

Comment: When you do the restore you should start run rman, connect to the target and run "CATALOG START WITH '/disk1/backups/';". You can then "LIST BACKUP;" which will show you the backups of the database to that directory, including the control file. Find the most recent backup of the control file and see what SCN it has, then find the most recent backup of any datafile. If the SCN for the newest backup of a control file is newer than the SCN for the newest backup of a datafile, the data base will need recovery to be consistent. No, you don't need the control file from three years ago.

Comment: You can tell rman to restore a specific control file. So if the backup contains more than one control file, use the oldest control file for the most recent backup.

Comment: @Gandolf989 im going to edit this post and put the output of the `list backup` and `list backup recoverable` commands. so you can tell me the best procedure to try to get the database to its previous state. also thanks for helping.

Comment: I would like to restore the Dec. 22 backup and open it so the database is the same as it was on that date.

Comment: I put the instructions below so that I could format the commands. You should be able to do everything in rman.

Answer (score 2):

---

## a)

The command `alter database open` showed:

```
ORA-01190: control file or data file 1 is from before the last RESETLOGS
ORA-01110: data file 1: '+DATA/db-name/datafile/system.333.741265951'
```

This can have several reasons but in your case it means that the database found redologs which do not fit the controlfile/datafiles. This probably happened like this:

1. You tried to restore the old backup without *deleting original files* / *moving original files somewhere else*. (I prefer option 2)
2. You come to the point where you should open the database with resetlogs option but you don't do it. You try to open the database normal and the database finds the redologs of the previous database which have the correct DBID but a different incarnation. Luckily the database realizes the fault and does not continue otherwise you would crash your fresh restored database.

---

## b)

You issued `alter database open resetlogs`:

After this command finished your database was open but your application still had problems. Well, first let's make this clear: At this point your database had the exact same data as before. Each block, each byte, each bit is now in the same place as before when you issued the backup. So the errors are not related to the database.

---

## c)

This is the procedure you have to follow. (I would not recommend offline backups but this is a different story.)

RMAN cold backup just works the way you did it. Here is my guide I wrote some time ago:

#### Cold Backup

1. shutdown the database
2. startup in mount mode (nomount does not work)
3. backup the database with `backup database;` and `backup current controlfile;`

#### Restore the Cold Backup

1. get a SPFILE
2. startup the database in nomount mode
3. restore the controlfile with `restore controlfile from '<controlfile backup>';`
4. make sure the controlfile knows all available backups. If not run a `catalog start with '<path>';` to search for backups.
5. restore the database with `restore database;`
6. In case of an online backup you would run a recovery now. But not with a cold backup.
7. Open the database with resetlogs.

---

Answer (score -1):

Commands to restore database without needing to apply redo. If you don;t want the database to roll forward make sure that there are no files in the archive log directory. You can tar and delete them or just move them elsewhere.

```
shutdown abort;
startup nomount;
restore controlfile from '/u02/backups/dbname/dbname_1cpqqnpv_1_1_20141222_1';
alter database mount;
restore database;
alter database open resetlogs;
```

Comment: So there is a down vote but no explanation about what I got wrong. Not very helpful.

Comment: tried this method and recieved the following errors: `RMAN-03002: failure of alter db command at 01/20/2015 09:16:40
ORA-01152: file 1 was not restored from a sufficiently old backup 
ORA-01110: data file 1: '+DATA/dbname/datafile/system.333.741265951'`

Comment: Did you restore the '/u02/backups/dbname/dbname_1cpqqnpv_1_1_20141222_1' controlfile? It would be easier if you showed every command that you used and all of the output. What I put above should have worked. Somehow you aren't getting Oracle to do the things that you need it to do to restore the backup without needing redo.